# Sharepoint 2010 Custom Search Result

Tags: sharepoint-search

I searched for this question,but have been unable to find an answer. Should be pretty straightforward.

I am attempting to edit the People Search Core Results web part for a team site so that the results page automatically includes all people reporting to a particular manager. I know that you use Results Query Options, and then Append Text to Query, but I have no idea what to enter in the Append Text to Query box to get the results I am looking for.

Does anyone know what to enter to only return results for people reporting to a certain manager?

Thanks in advance,
Andrew[image]

Answer (score 0):

You enter a fixed query, the same query that works in the search box. Generally you use the form : Managed Property=query term (or Managed Property:Query Term for a contains query) so for your query you would use:

```
Manager:McDermott
```

or

```
Manager="Matthew McDermott"
```

I should point out that by default the People:Manager field is not indexed. So You have to configure the search schema and add a new managed property and map People:Manager to a new Managed Property to make this work.